# How to merge multiple partial templates into one file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I'm using Ruby on Rails 3 to create my web app.
I don't want to create a template file for each tiny partial template so I tried to merge them into one file using `content_for` method but it doesn't works.

My ERB template files are as follows.

layout/_fragments.html.erb: contains contents of some partial templates

```
<% content_for :twitter_checkbox do -%>
  <% can_post_twitter = current_user && current_user.twitter_oauth %>
  <% label_text = can_post_twitter ? "Post to Twitter" : "Set up your Twitter account" %>
  <%= label_tag :twitter, label_text %>
  <%= check_box_tag :twitter, 0, false, :disabled => !can_post_twitter %>
<%- end %>

<% content_for :other_content_of_partial_template do -%> # content of another partial template
...
```

layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  ...
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
<%= render 'layouts/fragments', :formats => :erb %>
```

layouts/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@entry) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= content_for :twitter_checkbox %> # it shows nothing
<% end %>
```

What is wrong with this way? 
Are there any other better ways to write multiple partial templates into one file?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have run the `_form` partial before your main layout had the chance to run the `_fragments` partial, so when you display the fragments, they are not yet created.

The action is rendered before the layout, not after. Calling the `_fragments` from your action instead of from layout should make it clear whether this is the problem. At least, I believe so ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `=` sign in the second snippet which would tell Rails to display the returned text.

```
<%= form_for(@entry) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= content_for :twitter_checkbox %> # Note <%= - it should now show stuff
<% end %>
```